# Preciso de uma ajuda em Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

Então pessoal estou precisando de uma ajuda em algumas atividades de MySQL relacionadas a Trigger, basicamente são três Trigger.

Primeira Trigger deve funciona após uma update ou insert(algo que ainda vou colocar) o estoque em produto deve mudar para a quantidade comprada. Porém acaba mudando o estoque de todos os produtos, sei que é uma lógica simples mas não estou conseguindo pegar ela.

A segunda deve ser a cada venda o estoque deve diminuir onde a lógica não funciona completamente ainda

E por fim a ultima seria se caso uma compra for deletada e se tiver quantidade suficiente em estoque deve ser diminuído, caso não tenha deve ser cancelada.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS DBPEDIDO;
CREATE DATABASE DBPEDIDO;

USE DBPEDIDO;

CREATE TABLE PRODUTO (
    IDPRODUTO INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    , NOME VARCHAR(45)
    , ESTOQUE INT
    , PRIMARY KEY(IDPRODUTO)
);

CREATE TABLE COMPRA (
    IDCOMPRA INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    , IDPRODUTO INT NOT NULL
    , QTDE INT
    , PRECOUNITARIO NUMERIC(8,2)
    , PRIMARY KEY (IDCOMPRA)
    , FOREIGN KEY (IDPRODUTO) REFERENCES PRODUTO(IDPRODUTO)
);

CREATE TABLE VENDA (
    IDVENDA INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    , IDPRODUTO INT NOT NULL
    , QTDE INT
    , PRECOUNITARIO NUMERIC(8,2)
    , PRIMARY KEY (IDVENDA)
    , FOREIGN KEY (IDPRODUTO) REFERENCES PRODUTO(IDPRODUTO)
);

INSERT INTO PRODUTO(IDPRODUTO, NOME, ESTOQUE) VALUES(NULL, 'COLHER', 1);
INSERT INTO COMPRA(IDCOMPRA, IDPRODUTO, QTDE, PRECOUNITARIO) VALUES(NULL, 1, 452, 1);
INSERT INTO VENDA(IDVENDA, IDPRODUTO, QTDE, PRECOUNITARIO) VALUES(NULL, 1, 20, 2);

ALTER TABLE PRODUTO AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE COMPRA AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE VENDA AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

SELECT * FROM COMPRA;
SELECT * FROM PRODUTO;
SELECT * FROM VENDA;


DROP TRIGGER TR_VENDA_UPDATE;
DROP TRIGGER TR_COMPRA_DELETE;
DROP TRIGGER TR_PRODUTO_UPDATE;

-- ----------------------------------------------------- --
            -- trigger update produto--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TR_PRODUTO_UPDATE AFTER  UPDATE ON COMPRA FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE PRODUTO SET ESTOQUE = ( SELECT QTDE FROM COMPRA )

WHERE ESTOQUE =  ESTOQUE
-- testei com IDPRODUTO onde pensei que deveria modificar apenas o produto referente ao id
 $$
DELIMITER ; 
            -- trigger update produto--
-- ----------------------------------------------------- --

-- ----------------------------------------------------- --
           -- trigger update venda--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TR_VENDA_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE ON VENDA FOR EACH ROW

UPDATE PRODUTO SET ESTOQUE = (ESTOQUE - (SELECT QTDE from VENDA) ) 
where IDPRODUTO = IDPRODUTO

 $$
DELIMITER ;
            -- trigger update venda--
-- ----------------------------------------------------- --

-- ----------------------------------------------------- --
           -- trigger delete estoque--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TR_COMPRA_DELETE AFTER DELETE ON COMPRA FOR EACH ROW
IF cq = (select QTDE from COMPRA) >= pe = (select ESTOQUE FROM PRODUTO) THEN 
UPDATE PRODUTO SET  ESTOQUE = (cq - pe ) 
where ESTOQUE = ESTOQUE;
END IF
 $$
DELIMITER ;
            -- trigger delete estoque--
-- ------------------------------------------------------------- --
```

Comment: No primeiro trigger a linha `WHERE ESTOQUE =  ESTOQUE` vai ser sempre `true` então ele vai atualizar todas as linhas da tabela.

Comment: sim, ai é que está, quero apenas atualizar referente ao idproduto, atualizar produtos individualmente, entendes?

Comment: De uma lida nas palavras chave [`OLD` e `NEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)